# How to add Folder Actions in Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, folder-action

I'm trying to add an Apple Script to my Download directory. From what I read on the Internet I need to copy the script to Macintosh HD -> Libraries -> Scripts -> Folder Action Scripts - however, I don't see this directory on ML, what should I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to drag it into your personal library, not the system-wide.

- Switch to Finder
- <kbd>Shift-Cmd-G</kbd> and enter `~/Library/Scripts` to open a Finder window
- In case there isn't a `Folder Action Scripts` folder inside the newly opened window, just create one manually
- Copy the folder action scripts into the folder called `Folder Action Scripts`

Comment: I don't have the directory ~/Library/Scripts :(

Comment: Then create this folder as well by just going to `~/Library` in step 2.

Comment: OK, let me try this.

Comment: ~/Library is hidden in Finder, you can (among other ways) access it by using <kbd>Shift-Cmd-G</kbd>. And yes, your folder actions should be in your home folder (you don't have write access to `/Library/...` anyway).

Comment: OK, copied it and I can see it in Finder. Now I want to be able to link it to my ~/Downloads folder, I went into Finder Action Setup of ~/Downloads folder, but I can't find the script in the list - what should I do?

Comment: And what did you mean by "In case there isn't a Folder Action Scripts folder yes, just create one manually"? Isn't the creation of ~/Library/Scripts replaces this?

Comment: The full path is `~/Library/Scripts/Folder Action Scripts` so if `Scripts` missing create both `Scripts` and (inside the newly created folder) `Folder Action Scripts`. Your folder actions then need to be copied into `Folder Action Scripts`